# Swift: registerForKeyboardNotifications from UIViewController extension

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am trying to clean up my code and create and extension to `UIViewController` to register and deregister my keyboard. In my utility file I have the following:

```
extension UIViewController {
     //Register the keyboard for notifications in  viewDidLoad
     func registerForKeyboardNotifications() {

         //Adding notifies on keyboard appearing
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CreateEventVC.keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil) 
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CreateEventVC.keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

     }

     //Deregister the keyboard for notification in viewWillDisapper
     func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications() {

         //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
     }
}
```

What I need is the "CreateEventVC" in the `selector` to be the current `Class`.

Then I call it in my ViewController with the below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         //Register Keyboard
         registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()

}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {

        self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height

    }

}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {

        self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height

    }

}
```

I have a feeling this isn't the best practice.  Any help or advice will be great!

Answer (score 11):

I'm using `UIViewController` and `UIScrollView` extensions. If you're shifting your `UIView` you also can use this extension, but using `UIScrollView` is more convenient as it won't mess up with your view bounds and in case you need to add more textfields this approach is more generic.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func registerForKeyboardDidShowNotification(usingBlock block: ((NSNotification, CGSize) -> Void)? = nil) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { (notification) -> Void in
            let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
            guard let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.size else { fatalError("Can't grab the keyboard frame") }

            block?(notification, keyboardSize)
        })
    }

    func registerForKeyboardWillHideNotification(usingBlock block: (NSNotification -> Void)? = nil) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { (notification) -> Void in
            block?(notification)
        })
    }
}
```

so with this code, in your `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` method you can register for keyboards notifications and add any additional functions in blocks. Like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    registerForKeyboardDidShowNotification { notif, size in
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= size.height
    }

    registerForKeyboardWillHideNotification { notif in
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT: (For `UIScrollView`)

> 1)Can you animate the keyboard showing?

Actually keyboard appearance is always animated, so i think you're saying about the scrollview adjustments. Yes, you can. Below I posted updated `UIViewController` and `UIScrollView` extensions, which are handling that.

> 2) Do i need to deregister the keyboard?

Well, it's a good practice to avoid crashes in the future. For that you probably may prefer to add your notification in `viewWillAppear` and remove it in `viewWillDisappear` methods.

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(scrollView, name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(scrollView, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

> 3) For the UIScrollView method would I put all my objects in a scroll view in the screen then just programmatically scroll the view when each UITextField becomes the first responder?

You don't scroll anything programmatically. What you need to do is to change the insets of `UIScrollView` and it will automatically make the firstResponder visible on the screen.

This is the code I use in my projects:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func registerForKeyboardDidShowNotification(scrollView: UIScrollView, usingBlock block: (CGSize? -> Void)? = nil) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { (notification) -> Void in
            let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
            let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.size
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(scrollView.contentInset.top, scrollView.contentInset.left, keyboardSize!.height, scrollView.contentInset.right)

            scrollView.setContentInsetAndScrollIndicatorInsets(contentInsets)
            block?(keyboardSize)
        })
    }

    func registerForKeyboardWillHideNotification(scrollView: UIScrollView, usingBlock block: (Void -> Void)? = nil) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { (notification) -> Void in
            let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(scrollView.contentInset.top, scrollView.contentInset.left, 0, scrollView.contentInset.right)
            scrollView.setContentInsetAndScrollIndicatorInsets(contentInsets)
            block?()
        })
    }
}



extension UIScrollView {
    func setContentInsetAndScrollIndicatorInsets(edgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets) {
        self.contentInset = edgeInsets
        self.scrollIndicatorInsets = edgeInsets
    }
}
```

And in your `viewWillAppear` method, just add it like this:

```
registerForKeyboardWillShowNotification(scrollView)
registerForKeyboardWillHideNotification(scrollView)
```

And it will shrink the scrollview's contentInset whenever the keyboard appears and expand it whenever keyboard disappears.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  A couple questions: 1) Can you animate the keyboard showing? 2) Do i need to deregister the keyboard? 3) For the `UIScrollView` method would I put all my objects in a scroll view in the screen then just programmatically scroll the view when each `UITextField` becomes the first responder?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Manstof Ok, I'll update my answer for `UIScrollView`.

Comment: I have been playing with all the answers you have provided and the `UIScrollView` has been working the best!  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @noir. This solved my purpose. Consider converting it to latest swift syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Here're the Swift 4 extension with a method where you need put Constraint inside:

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {

    func bindKeypad(to constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self, weak constraint] notification in
            guard let info = notification.userInfo else { return }
            guard let height = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)?.size.height else { return }
            guard constraint?.constant != height else { return }
            constraint?.constant = height
            self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self, weak constraint] _ in
            guard constraint?.constant != 0 else { return }
            constraint?.constant = 0
            self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

and in your class on deinit call:

```
deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
```

to use it call in viewDidLoad:

```
bindKeypad(to: bottomKeypadConstraint)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think we can create BaseController which contain keyboard events, we have to inherit our viewController from it and override keyboard method like viewWiillAppear (keyboardWillAppear or keyboardWillDisappear)

Requirment

```
class BaseController: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    //****************************************************
    //MARK: - Keyboard event listener
    //****************************************************

    @objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
       //Override this method
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        //Override this method
    }
}
```

How to use

```
class ViewController:BaseController {
    override func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        // Do something
    }
    override func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Made an edit, in waiting for review: but calling super.viewWillAppear in the viewWillDisappear function could cause some tricky stuff.. so you probably don't want to just copy paste this.

Comment: Yo @adams.s thnx